# LPMetadataProvider For LPLinkView Is Slow and Intensive

Tags: swift, swiftui

Using LPMetadataProvider to obtain an LPLinkView in swift will spike the cpu to 100% and takes anywheres between 5 and 10 seconds just to fetch 20 links.

This can be a big problem because fetching meta data requires you to be on the main thread. So far I've either had to increase my loading times for the view I'm using this in, or leave it to fetch while the view is active, but that kills scrolling performance.

Does anyone have suggestions for how to make it faster?

Here's a test example.

```
import SwiftUI
import LinkPresentation
import Combine

struct PicSum: Decodable, Identifiable{
    var id: String
    var download_url: String
}

class ContentModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var time:Double = 0
    @Published var links = [RichLink]()
    @Published var isLoading = false
    var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    let picSumURL = URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=2&limit=20")!

    func fetchLinks(){
        links.removeAll()
        isLoading = true
        time = 0
        let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: picSumURL)
            .map(\.data)
            .decode(type: [PicSum].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .flatMap { picSumArray in
                Publishers.MergeMany(
                    picSumArray
                        .map{URL(string: $0.download_url)!}
                        .map(self.fetchLink)
                )
            }
            .map{RichLink(for: $0)}
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            .sink(receiveCompletion: {_ in
                print("Finished loading all links.")
                self.isLoading = false
            }, receiveValue: {link in
                self.links.append(link)
                self.time = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start
            }).store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
    
    private func fetchLink(for url: URL) -> AnyPublisher <LPLinkMetadata, Error> {
        let metadataProvider = LPMetadataProvider()
        
        return Future { promise in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                metadataProvider.startFetchingMetadata(for: url) { (metadata, error) in
                    if let metadata = metadata{
                        promise(Result.success(metadata))
                    } else if let error = error{
                        promise(Result.failure(error))
                    } else {
                        fatalError()
                    }
                }
            }
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = ContentModel()
    
    var body: some View{
        NavigationView{
            List{
                Text("\(model.links.count) links obtained in \(String(format: "%.2f", model.time)) seconds.")
                    .font(.headline)
                ForEach(model.links){ link in
                    LinkView(richLink: link)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Slow Rich Links")
            .toolbar{
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing){
                    Button("Fetch"){
                        model.fetchLinks()
                    }.disabled(model.isLoading)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}


class RichLink: NSObject, Identifiable {
    var id: Int!
    var metadata: LPLinkMetadata!
    
    init(for metadata: LPLinkMetadata) {
        super.init()
        id = Int(Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
        self.metadata = metadata
    }
}


struct LinkView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var richLink: RichLink
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> LPLinkView {
        guard let metadata = richLink.metadata else {
            return LPLinkView()
        }
        let linkView = LPLinkView(metadata: metadata)
        return linkView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: LPLinkView, context: Context) {
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried your code, the main thread is not blocked while the metadata is downloaded, indeed the metadata download needs to start from the main thread (seems a webview is involved here for download), however while the download is in progress I can interact with the UI.

Comment: You are able to interact with the UI, however its very choppy.

Comment: Is it still the case that the metadata download needs to start from the main thread? If so, were you able to find a workable way to do this?

Comment: Seems so. I've found no workaround.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, using `LPLinkView`s in a `List` takes a big performance hit and causes memory leaks. Consider using a `VStack` embedded inside a `ScrollView`.

```
ScrollView {
    VStack {
        ForEach(links, id: \.self) { link in
            if let url = URL(string: link) {
                LinkRow(url: url)
            }
        }
    }
    .padding()
}
```

I have done this saw a significant improvement over using a `List`.